# Generate single typings.d.ts file for component TSX component library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a build pipeline to make publishing my TSX React component library to npm easier, and i'm looking for a way to have typescript look at a file like this....

```
import { Button } from "./components/Button/Button";
import Checkbox from "./components/Checkbox/Checkbox";

export {
    Button,
    Checkbox
}
```

^^ Main.tsx
and output the typings for Button.tsx and Checkbox.tsx into a single file (typings.d.ts)

ideallly tsc --declaration main.tsx would do it, but it doesn't.

Abit of context would also be that i point webpack at this file as a entry point, to get a bundle so if webpack can be configured to figure out the typings and bundle them aswell that would also be ideal.